# Duplicate class found error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, payu

This is my error

```
Duplicate class org.json.JSONWriter found in modules jetified-java-json (java-json.jar) and jetified-json-20090211 (org.json:json:20090211)
Duplicate class org.json.XML found in modules jetified-java-json (java-json.jar) and jetified-json-20090211 (org.json:json:20090211)
Duplicate class org.json.XMLTokener found in modules jetified-java-json (java-json.jar) and jetified-json-20090211 (org.json:json:20090211)
 
Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

I have added a payu dependency after that this error is poping up .In this project it has old payu sdk

Comment: Hi @Ajay, Can you provide us with more details regarding this problem?? ex:- code you have tried, what you expected result, etc.. please read the guidance on asking a question in StackOverflow. Then someone will help you to resolve your issue

Comment: This means that JSONWriter class and XMLTokener are used in more than one dependencies and also mean there is a difference in VERSIONS, you have to declare only one dependency or just update the old one.

Comment: @Deshan-Charuka actually it was a old project my old college added few sdk at that time.It worked good till now, the issue arise while adding payu latest dependency .